# Naming for id column with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data with express.js on the server and a mysql backend. The problem is that my existing database structure uses a prefix for the id column:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Order', {
  primaryKey: 'ord_id',
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 7,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    bulkCommit: false
  })
});

App.Order = DS.Model.extend();
```

It seems that ember-data requires an 'id' field. Is there a way to map it to my 'ord_id'?

EDIT: I had to define the map before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Post', {
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

This is part of ember data, revision 5. I think this is what you need to do...

Comment: Ok, I see that I should have used App.Adapter.map to map the id but now I get the error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.hide()')" I edited my original code to show what I am using.

Comment: I needed to define the map before using the adapter. Thx for your help.